# CakePHP connections while testing

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i am currently trying to unit test some of my code. I am executing some manually entered SQL statements like this:

```
$db = ConnectionManager::get('default');
...
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

I assumed that whenever I run unit tests and request the `default` connection I will get the `test` connection instead. If it is not defined in my config it will throw an exception.
When I run a test which executes a statement against the database it is always executed against the `default` connection. The `test` connection is never used.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

My database config is as follows:

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'dbname',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
    ],

    /**
     * The test connection is used during the test suite.
     */
    'test' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'dbname_test',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
    ],
]
```

Thanks for any help!

***Edit***
I think the documentation is wrong:

> By default CakePHP will alias each connection in your application. Each connection defined in your application’s bootstrap that does not start with test_ will have a test_ prefixed alias created. Aliasing connections ensures, you don’t accidentally use the wrong connection in test cases. Connection aliasing is transparent to the rest of your application. For example if you use the ‘default’ connection, instead you will get the test connection in test cases. If you use the ‘replica’ connection, the test suite will attempt to use ‘test_replica’.

[Link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#test-connections)

You can read there that CakePHP is aliasing the `default` connection automatically to `test` when running unit tests. To get that behaviour you have to define that alias yourself in your phpunit bootstrap.php like so:

```
\Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager::alias('test', 'default');
```

You can read about that here [ConnectionManager::alias](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Datasource.ConnectionManager.html#_alias) The funny thing is that the documentation for `alias` explicitly states

> For example, if you alias 'default' to 'test', fetching 'default' will always return the 'test' connection as long as the alias is defined.

Comment: The `test` configuration is used when you use `ClassRegistry::init` to instantiate a model. When you use a manual connection like you're using, you need to manually get the `test` connection. It's worth noting that in CakePHP 3.0 the `default` connection will be aliased to the test settings to prevent this sort of problem.

Comment: What you expected normally is the default behavior. Make sure that you are using the correct PHPUnit configuration, and that it includes the listener for the CakePHP Fixture Injector, as this is where the `default => test` alias is being configured.

Comment: @jeremyharris This question is about CakePHP 3.x, which works differently.

Comment: @ndm yeah I just noticed that, jumped the gun a bit and got your comment while I edited my original.

Comment: @jeremyharris If the `default` connection gets aliased to `test` my code above should work, right? Or do I have to get the connection name differently?

Comment: I solved my confusion :-) You have to do a `\Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager::alias('test', 'default');` in your test-bootstrap. The documentation of testing in CakePHP tells me this is done for me by CakePHP itself, but this seems to be false: [CakePHP Book - Testing](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#test-connections) They state: `For example if you use the ‘default’ connection, instead you will get the test connection in test cases.`

Comment: No, it's true, as I've mentioned this happens via the fixture injector, to be exact, it happens in [**`FixtureManager::_aliasConnections()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.1/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureManager.php#L89). You should debug why the testsuite doesn't seem to make it to there.

Comment: The testing docs seem to leave out an important part about creating a bootstrap file. Usually I copy Cake's test bootstrap (and modify), or DebugKit if I'm working on a plugin. Since you're not using fixtures you didn't get some of the automatic aliasing functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection aliasing is done by default when you load the fixtures manager listener in our phpunit.xml config as it is distributed in the app template:

https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/phpunit.xml.dist#L23-L31

Comment: Accepting this as the answer. As @jerremyharris pointed out in the comments above the docs leave out the part of creating a bootstrap file.

Answer (score 3):

We also had the same error, for some tables tests were getting default db instead of test db for no reason. In the end using code at the top of the setUp function (before parent::setUp()) solved the problem (we have a main test class from which we extend all tests, do some setting up. We put it there)

```
TableRegistry::clear();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solution helped me too!